# Android: How to disable the default orange borders in webview when click the links

Tags: android, google-chrome, jquery-mobile, webview

I'm using JQueryMobile to develop a hybird app for android. Anybody who knows how to disable the annoying orange borders in WebView which added by the system when I click the links, buttons.

[image]

I tried with the styles
`-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);`  and `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);`and 100% sure it does not work on my device.

Is there any configuration or coding I can make in WebView to disable the borders?

Comment: Try `-webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);` (both)

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh I think it still does not work for me and the text in the label becomes editable.

Answer (score 2):

Tested on Nexus 10 (Android 4.4.2).
This worked for me:

```
.affected-element {
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
body,div{
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Is this piece of code you're looking for?

Comment: I am using this in my code and is working on Android 4.0 and above(I tested on these devices). You can fix this style for a particular div also

Comment: sorry!! apologies for not studying the question clear.
    body,div,a,input,p,img{
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }. Try this

Comment: Still not work. I think using styles can not resolve my issue I'm wondering whether I can do some configuration in WebView. Anyway, thanks for your answers.

Answer (score -1):

I have the following css to remove that orange outline in several HTML elements:

```
div:focus, div:active, button:focus, button:active, a:focus, a:active { 
    outline: none; 
}
```

It worked pretty well for me so far ;)